# How to create thread pool for stream operation

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, threadpool

I like to control the thread execution when using streams with a thread pool. Currently I have List of string

```
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList() {"1","2","3","4"}; //that holds the strings 
List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>{} // holds function that manipulate the strings from mylist
```

Each action have work method that get the String from mylist.

```
Stream<String> stream = mylist.parallelStream();
stream = stream.flatMap(s-> actions.stream().map(ac -> ac.work(str)));
r = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

All work great but I have no control on the thread pool, know I can use ForkJoinPool as in this example:

[Example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool)

But I didn't found way to implement it in my example. This for example doesn't work:

```
   ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
            r= customThreadPool.submit(
                    () -> mylist.parallelStream().flatMap(s-> actions.stream().map(ac -> ac.work(str))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

gives me error:

```
java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T,R,A,capture#1 of ?,T exist so that java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask<T> conforms to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? That is how you do it. The `parallelStream()` will use threads from the `customThreadPool`, not from the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`, and you have full control over the `customThreadPool`.

Comment: something in the syntax is worng as it gives me :
')' expected

Comment: Don't show error in a comment. Edit the question and clarify it by showing what you mean by "not working".

Comment: when i add ) it gives me :
java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T,R,A,capture#1 of ?,T exist so that java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask<T> conforms to java.util.List<java.lang.String>

Comment: @Andreas i did it in the question

Comment: What is the type of `r`?  Looks like that might be the problem; you might need to add a final `.get()` or `.join()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code compiles and runs fine, once the code errors are fixed (`str` => `s`).

**Common Pool**

```java
// Setup with dummy actions for testing which thread executes the action
List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4")); //that holds the strings 
List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        s -> { s += "x";  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + s); return s; },
        s -> { s += "y";  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + s); return s; }
        ));

// Using common pool
Stream<String> stream = mylist.parallelStream();
stream = stream.flatMap(s -> actions.stream().map(ac -> ac.work(s)));
List<String> r = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(r);
```

*Output*

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7: 1x
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3: 2x
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3: 2y
main: 3x
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5: 4x
main: 3y
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7: 1y
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5: 4y
[1x, 1y, 2x, 2y, 3x, 3y, 4x, 4y]
```

**Custom Pool**

```java
ForkJoinPool customThreadPool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
ForkJoinTask<List<String>> task = customThreadPool.submit(
        () -> mylist.parallelStream().flatMap(s -> actions.stream().map(ac -> ac.work(s))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(task.get());
```

If the compiler complains as described in the question, you need to help it choose the correct overload of `submit()` by casting the lambda expression in the 3rd line:

```java
        (Callable<List<String>>) () -> mylist.parallelStream().flatMap(s -> actions.stream().map(ac -> ac.work(s))).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

*Output*

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3: 3x
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: 1x
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1: 1y
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5: 2x
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: 4x
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7: 4y
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5: 2y
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3: 3y
[1x, 1y, 2x, 2y, 3x, 3y, 4x, 4y]
```

**Single Thread**

```java
Stream<String> stream = mylist.stream();
stream = stream.flatMap(s -> actions.stream().map(ac -> ac.work(s)));
List<String> r = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(r);
```

*Output*

```
main: 1x
main: 1y
main: 2x
main: 2y
main: 3x
main: 3y
main: 4x
main: 4y
[1x, 1y, 2x, 2y, 3x, 3y, 4x, 4y]
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer, where do you recommend learning more about streams?